# PHP parse URL image directory

Tags: php

I have some script which output the images, with an interval of 5 seconds, on a screen.
All images are in a directory called `images/easter`.
The URL to display the webpage is `http://'localhost'/index.php`.
In the `index.php` I have a variable: `$directory = 'images/easter/`.

We want users create a new image directory and upload pictures to it (eg `images/holiday`).
The new images have to be displayed with a simple change in the url.

```
http://'localhost'/index.php?holiday
```

I think this can be done by URL parsing in PHP. But how to script this?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You can make your url like this http://'localhost'/index.php?q=holiday , and use $_GET['q'] for getting access to your parameter

Comment: How is the axact syntact? This will not work: $directory = 'images/'.((isset($_GET['q'])) ; with http://localhost/harald/index.php?q=test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make your url something like

```
http://localhost/index.php?dir=holiday
```

or just

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

In your script do the following:

```
<?php
$directory = 'images/'.((isset($_GET['dir'])) ? $_GET['dir'] : 'easter');
```

But be sure to check weather the input is valid, so that it is not possible to output the content of a private folder.

If you want Urls like

```
http://localhost/holiday
```

you shold take a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use $_GET to retrieve the desired values from the URL. You'd have to adapt it slightly though. Maybe you want something like `http://'localhost'/index.php?dir=holiday`. That way, you can use $_GET on dir.
[PHP Form handling](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_forms.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so far for the answers.

We do not want to edit the files, so the change have to be in the URL from where the pictures are taken.

My knowledge of PHP is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_GET parameters.

**URL :**

```
http://'localhost'/index.php?q=holiday
```

**Code :**

```
$directory = 'images/'((isset($_GET['q']))?$_GET['q']:'');
```

or

```
if (isset($_GET['q']))
    $directory = 'images/'.$_GET['q'];
else
    $directory = 'images';
```